# Trigger not Updating Associated Record

Tags: trigger, apex

The trigger below was created to update a custom check box field on the standard account object called "Billed" when a field called "Balance is 0.00 in zuora" is true. The issue is that field is not be updated on the account when made true on the quote.

```
trigger QuoteBilled on zqu__Quote__c (after insert, after update) {
List<Account> accountsToUpdateList = new List<Account>();
    Set<Id> accountsToUpdate = new Set<Id>();
    for(zqu__Quote__c Q : Trigger.New)
    {
        if(Q.Balance_is_0_00_in_Zuora__c)
            accountsToUpdate.add(Q.zqu__Account__c);
    }
    for(Account acc : [Select Billed__c from Account where id in :accountsToUpdate])
    {
        acc.Billed__c = true;
        accountsToUpdateList.add(acc);
    }
    if(accountsToUpdateList.size() > 0)
        update accountsToUpdateList;

}
```

Comment: Have you checked field level security for 'Balance_is_0_00_in_Zuora__c' and 'Billed__c'?

Comment: Shouldn't matter for a trigger - only an issue if you are using a trigger helper.

Comment: Have you put a bunch of debug statements throughout your code? Print out all the lists and see what's in them.

Comment: You might already have checked this, but are there any Workflow Field Updates on the Billed__c field that might be overriding your update?

Answer (score 0):

According to Your Question

```
when a field called "Balance is 0.00 in zuora" is true
```

In your First For/If Loop you are not checking **Q.Balance_is_0_00_in_Zuora__c** is TRUE or not

If `Balance_is_0_00_in_Zuora__c`is a Checkbox then in your for loop should be like this

```
for(zqu__Quote__c Q : Trigger.New)
    {
        if(Q.Balance_is_0_00_in_Zuora__c==True)
            accountsToUpdate.add(Q.zqu__Account__c);
    }
```

Comment: As long as `Q.Balance_is_0_00_in_Zuora__c` is never null (which it never is for checkboxes) `Q.Balance_is_0_00_in_Zuora__c` and `Q.Balance_is_0_00_in_Zuora__c==True` give the identical results.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty new to development, but shouldn't the line

for(Account acc : [Select Billed__c from Account where id in :accountsToUpdate])

be

for(accountsToUpdate acc : [Select ID, Billed__c from Account where id = acc.id])

I feel like the original line doesn't actually run?

Comment: Hi there, thanks for your input, you should post your answer as a comment instead, in so far that it is really not an answer but more a question.

Comment: Sorry.  New user.
Should I delete my post and resubmit as comment?

Comment: Yep, that's the one.